# I have a 2000 BMW 540i. I have been getting "check coolant level" from the computer recently.

Tags: coolant, bmw, radiator

Twice in a week the radiator has been low on fluid. I have added water to it to refill. I was told that I should use coolant/water mix instead of just water as it is most likely evaporating from the radiator. Could someone explain the procedure to bleed any trapped air from the radiator? I have never had to deal with this issue before. Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 1):

this is a serious condition which should not be neglected.

I have been driving a 320I with a similar condition. The solution was to change the radiator and all hoses connected to it.

If you decide to only change a leaking hose, consequences will lead to radiator popping while driving on a highway.  BMW recommended to change the whole thing(radiator,and all hoses) but we did not listen to them and this resulted I n the radiator being blown while driving at high speed on a highway.